# php search in a specified folder

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to write a PHP function that searches for a file in a specified folder.  The if function doesn't work properly both blocks of code get executed, here's the code.

```
 <?php

$dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsearchbox/forms";
$dirtest = "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsearchbox\forms" ;
$dh  = opendir($dir);


while (false != ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
$files[] = $filename;}

$indexCount = count($files);

for( $index=0 ; $index<$indexCount ; $index++)

{    $post_path = $dir . $files[$index];
     $post_patharray []= $post_path;
     $post_pathtest=$dirtest.$files[$index];
    $filesize= number_format(filesize($files[$index]));
    $filesizearray []= $filesize;

$wantedfile = substr($post_patharray[$index], 34 , -4);
$wantedfilearray [] = $wantedfile;
$wantedfile1 = substr($post_patharray[$index], 34);
$wantedfile1array [] = $wantedfile1;
$filetype = substr($post_patharray[$index], -3);

$searchbox = $_POST['search'];
$searchResult = array_search($searchbox, $files,false);

         if($searchbox == $wantedfilearray[$index] )
{           
             echo("<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='-90' > <br>");
             echo ("<tr align='left'>");
             echo('<TD bgcolor="#737374" width="12.9%">');
             echo("<div style='position: relative'");
             echo ("<p size='0.5'>$wantedfile1array[$index]</p>");
             echo ("</div></td>");
             echo ('<td bgcolor="#737374" width="38%">');
             echo("<div style='position: relative'");
             echo ("<p size='1'><a href=\"$files[$index]\"  target='_blank' > C:\ xampp\ htdocs \ phpsearchbox \ forms \ $files[$index]</a><p>");
             echo ("</div></td>");
             echo('<td text-align="justify" bgcolor="#737374" width="15%"> ');
             echo('<div ');
             echo ("<p>$filetype</p>");
             echo("</div></td>");
             echo('<td bgcolor="#737374" width="15%">');
             echo("<div style='position: relative'");
             echo("<p> $filesizearray[$index]</p>");
             echo("</div></td>");
             echo("</TR>\n");
             echo ("</table>");

}
else
{echo ("<br><br><b><font face='Arial' size='2'>sorry! no documents found, please try another ID</font></b>");
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Try changing the directory path as C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phpsearchbox\\forms.

Comment: i tried changing the path but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = 'E:\\';
echo '<pre>';
foreach (glob($dir . '*.dll') as $filename) {
    echo $filename, '<br/>', 'PROPERTIES:<br/>';
    print_r(stat($filename));
}
```

You can simply implement this logic using [Glob](http://php.net/glob) and [Stat](http://php.net/stat) function

**GLOB:**

- whose first parameter is the search pattern (according to libc pattern matching)
- second parameter is list of flags

  - GLOB_MARK - Adds a slash to each directory returned
  - GLOB_NOSORT - Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting). When this flag is not used, the pathnames are sorted alphabetically
  - GLOB_NOCHECK - Return the search pattern if no files matching it were found
  - GLOB_NOESCAPE - Backslashes do not quote metacharacters
  - GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'
  - GLOB_ONLYDIR - Return only directory entries which match the pattern
  - GLOB_ERR - Stop on read errors (like unreadable directories), by default errors are ignored.

**STAT:**

- Which give information or properties of a file both in numerical and associative index

also stat's value are depend on your operating system especially if you use windows read documentation clearly where it comes 0 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `for` block. Your `for` block starts as 0. Your `$indexCount` starts at 1 if a file is returned and will increase for each file that is found in the `$dh` directory.

You then loop over each file and compare the names, `echo`ing if the file found matches the name or saying there were no files found. I'd guess that your directory has 2 files in it. One matches, and fires the `if` statement. The other doesn't match, and fires the `else` statement. It appears that both are firing - and they are - though because there are two different files, not because you have both blocks firing for the same file.

**EDIT**

Using your code above, I'd do the following:

```
class FileSearch {
    const DIR = "C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsearchbox/forms";
    const DIR_TEST = "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsearchbox\forms";

    public function search($searchbox) {
        $return = null;
        $dh  = opendir(self::DIR);

        $files = [];
        while (false != ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
            $files[] = $filename;
        }

        $indexCount = count($files);

        for( $index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            $post_path = self::DIR . $files[$index];
            $post_patharray[] = $post_path;
            $post_pathtest = self::DIR_TEST.$files[$index]; 
            $filesize = number_format(filesize($files[$index]));
            $filesizearray[] = $filesize;

            $wantedfile = substr($post_patharray[$index], strlen(self::DIR) , -4);
            $wantedfilearray[] = $wantedfile;
            $wantedfile1 = substr($post_patharray[$index], strlen(self::DIR));
            $wantedfile1array[] = $wantedfile1;
            $filetype = substr($post_patharray[$index], -3);

            $searchResult = array_search($searchbox, $files,false);

            if($searchbox == $wantedfilearray[$index] ) {
                $return .= "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='-90' > <br>";
                $return .= "<tr align='left'>";
                $return .= '<TD bgcolor="#737374" width="12.9%">';
                $return .= "<div style='position: relative'";
                $return .= "<p size='0.5'>$wantedfile1array[$index]</p>";
                $return .= "</div></td>";
                $return .= '<td bgcolor="#737374" width="38%">';
                $return .= "<div style='position: relative'";
                $return .= "<p size='1'><a href=\"$files[$index]\"  target='_blank' > C:\ xampp\ htdocs \ phpsearchbox \ forms \ $files[$index]</a><p>";
                $return .= "</div></td>";
                $return .= '<td text-align="justify" bgcolor="#737374" width="15%"> ';
                $return .= '<div ';
                $return .= "<p>$filetype</p>";
                $return .= "</div></td>";
                $return .= '<td bgcolor="#737374" width="15%">';
                $return .= "<div style='position: relative'";
                $return .= "<p> $filesizearray[$index]</p>";
                $return .= "</div></td>";
                $return .= "</TR>\n";
                $return .= "</table>";
            } else {
                $return =  "<br><br><b><font face='Arial' size='2'>sorry! no documents found, please try another ID</font></b>";
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }

}

$mySearcher = new FileSearch();
echo $mySearcher->search($_POST['search']);
```

You should separate your view from your controller - meaning that you shouldn't be coding in the HTML into your PHP function. You should simply return the needed data from your function and then format it as needed in your page. For more info, see [this SitePoint MVC framework tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)

Comment: how do you suggest i can fix it?

Comment: I've added some code that will help solve this problem. I changed the structure a bit to include the `FileSearch` class to encapsulate your code.

Comment: when i click on the search button it shows an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysearcher.php on line 58

Comment: You'll want to go to line 58 and figure out why you have an extra "}" in there.

Comment: its not extra its for the else block and i couldn't find any extra "}"